# Need to do nested transaction more than 2 levels over Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-6

I'm using EF 6, and by business requirement, database operation will require more than 2 nested transaction.

As far as I know, current way to do nested transaction is using System.Transaction.TransactionScope as 1st level, then use DbContextTransaction as 2nd level.

Now I need to do a 3rd nested transaction, 1 more level down, is this doable with EF?

Comment: A workaround to emulate nested transaction, just to address my need https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4d359652-d3ff-4127-bb94-c7bd40ba58c7/entity-framework-6-partially-using-transactionscope?forum=adodotnetentityframework